# Generating a Test Certificate for Windows 10 UWP with 10 years expiry

Tags: uwp

I have generated a certificate using following Powershell Command:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type Custom -Subject "CN=Something" -TextExtension @("2.5.29.37={critical}{text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3", "2.5.29.19={text}") -KeyUsage DigitalSignature -FriendlyName "Friendly Name" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\My" -NotBefore (Get-Date) -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(10)
```

Then I am exporting it using following command:

```
Export-PfxCertificate -cert "Cert:\LocalMachine\My\00fa4dd7524315b780abaa9cb70dc4755da1103c" -FilePath C:\testcertificate.pfx -Password $pwd
```

Now when I am using this certificate from Package.appxmanifest file. It is throwing following error:

[image]

I am using Visual Studio 2017 with SDK Version 1809

I have also tried to export using Certificate Management Snap in MMC.

What am I missing?

Comment: So turns out that I need to import the certificate first into my system certificate store. When I run visual studio as admin, it is not failing.

Comment: If this works for you, post it as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the Powershell commands, but you can do this with the normal SDK commands `makecert`, `pvk2pfx`, and `certutil`.

You can get a sample batch file [from this GitHub project](https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/SigningCerts) but the basic commands are as follows (using an expiry date of 1/1/2030):

```
makecert /n CN=foo /r /h 0 /eku "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3,1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.13" /e 1/1/2030 /sv foo.pvk foo.cer

pvk2pfx /pvk foo.pvk /spc foo.cer /pfx foo.pfx

certutil -addstore TrustedPeople foo.cer
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try skipping signing checks.

Open the project file (.csproj), and add the following line under the first `PropertyGroup` element.

```
<EnableSigningChecks>false</EnableSigningChecks>
```

Comment: Can we sideload after skipping signing checks?

Comment: It works in my test. - Edit: we have been doing this for years.